# How to pass GitLab CI file variable to Dockerfile and docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, devops

GitLab CI allows adding custom variables to a project.

It allows to use a secret variable of type `file` where I specify a Key that is the variable name and Value that is the content of a file(e.g. content of certificate)

Then during execution of the pipeline the content will be saved as a temporary file and calling the variable name will return the path to the created file.

Ultimately I need to copy this file to a Docker container that is created when building the project. (`docker build ...` in the yml)

When testing if the variable works, I tried `echo $VARIABLE` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and it works, returns path of temp file. But when doing `RUN echo $VARIABLE` in the `Dockerfile`, it is empty. Therefore I also cannot use `ADD $VARIABLE /tmp/` which is my goal.

Is there a way to solve this and make this file available to the `Dockerfile`? I am new to Docker and GitLab and not sure where else to look.

Comment: This is answered better here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229182/simplest-way-of-passing-all-host-environment-variables-to-docker-container

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Had to use .yml file `docker build` argument `--build-arg VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value` and in Dockerfile use `ARG VARIABLE_NAME` so the Dockerfile knows it needs to use variable from environment.

Comment: It should be actually --build-arg VARIABLE=VARIABLE . So you have to give the variable a name :)

Comment: @FlorianFalk my command is not working                 - docker build --build-arg CHECK_STAGE=${CHECK_STAGE} -t ${IMAGE}:latest -t ${IMAGE}:${VERSION}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} -t ${IMAGE}:${VERSION} .

Comment: @KaranKhurana If you need help, you must also give others the opportunity to understand your problem. Just a command with the hint that it doesn't work is a bit little ;)

Also, I think comments are a wrong way to ask for help. I recommend you to open a new question.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, it's not possible like this because the file from CI/CD variable are copied at build time into a tmp directory ($CI_PROJECT_DIR.tmp) which is not in the docker build context. However, `ADD` need files present in the build context as [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

A workaround could be to copy the content of file in the current directory (supposing the Dockerfile is in `${CI_PROJECT_DIR}`) before the docker build command :

```
cat $VARIABLE > ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\mynewfile
```

and refer the the file in the Dockerfile :

```
ADD mynewfile /tmp/
```

Comment: thx! `cp $VARIABLE ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\mynewfile` also works, instead of `cat`

Answer (score 3):

I made a similar thing with the maven settings:

```
before_script:
  - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/
  - cp $M2_SETTINGS ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/settings.xml && chmod 600 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/settings.xml
```

**EDIT:**

you can also pass `- s .m2/settings.xml` to the mvn command if you pushed the settings.xml to you branch (which I recommend to be honest)

Answer (score -1):

You should try doing something like this:

`ADD ${VARIABLE}/tmp`

Comment: This is not exact, like @robliv said `--build-arg` and `ARG` are necessary. Check this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600106/2653911).