# How to pass GitLab CI file variable to docker container?

Tags: docker, pip, gitlab, gitlab-ci

This question is a little like this question. [How to pass GitLab CI file variable to Dockerfile and docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939500/how-to-pass-gitlab-ci-file-variable-to-dockerfile-and-docker-container)

I used the most voted answer however I failed.

The below is what I want to do.

I set up the **gitlab ci variable** called PIP_CONFIG with **file** type.
and the value is like

```
[global]
timeout = 60
```

in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
 ...
 - docker build -t $IMAGe
   --build-arg PIP_CONFIG=$PIP_CONFIG
   src/.
...
```

in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ARG PIP_CONFIG
RUN mkdir ~/.pip
RUN echo $PIP_CONFIG > ~/.pip/pip.conf
...
...
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then I got an error

```
Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains no section headers.
file: '/root/.pip/pip.conf', line: 1
'/builds/xxx/xxx/project_name.tmp/PIPCONFIG\n'   <<<< this line
...
```

It seems like it only wrote the path of temp file rather than the content of file.

I also try use `COPY $PIP_CONFIG ~/.pip/pip.conf` but it said the path is not exsist in `/builds/xxx/xxx/project_name.tmp/PIPCONFIG`.

Could someone tell me what should I do correctly? Thanks.

PS: The reason why I do not write the config directly in repository and jus use `COPY` from repo is that there is some sensitive token in  pip config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try, I understand that just use type 'variable' in the gitlab ci setting.

And then pass the value with quote("$VARABLE") for maybe you have the space or break line in your value.

like this
in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
 ...
 - docker build -t $IMAGe
   --build-arg PIP_CONFIG="$PIP_CONFIG"
   src/.
...
```

Remember add quote for `Dockerfile`, too.

```
FROM python:3
ARG PIP_CONFIG
RUN mkdir ~/.pip
RUN echo "$PIP_CONFIG" > ~/.pip/pip.conf
...
...
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then, I can do what I want, write a pip config to image from gitlab ci variable.

Hope can help others.